# How to pass string from swift to javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, swift3

Hello Guys I have an app which loads a web view and i have the data copied in my clipboard. I want to paste it in a text field on the web view. I have a function which does that in my javascript. I used [this link's marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343125/how-to-pass-data-from-swift-to-javascript) and it works fine when my pasteboard has an int(ex: 123456). But if I have a string or even a character in between the numbers (ex: 123n456) the javascript function doesn't get called. 
Here is my code:-

```
let pb: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        let myVal: String? = pb.string
        let MyValue: String = myVal!
        self.myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "fillText(\(myVal ?? MyValue ));")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add single quotation marks:

```
self.myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "fillText('\(myVal ?? MyValue )');")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yun it was a great help. It worked :). Thanks again